# Rotate a string N times in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm looking for a way to rotate a string to the left N times. Here are some examples:

Let the string be `abcdef`

- if I rotate it `1` time I want
  `bcdefa`
- if I rotate it `2` time I want
  `cdefab`
- if I rotate it `3` time I want
  `defabc`
- .
- .
- If I rotate the string its string
  length times, I should get back the
  original string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 $rotated = substr($str, $n) . substr($str, 0, $n);
```

Comment: Wouldn't work if `$n` is greater than the length of the string though, would it?

Comment: This will return the original string if $n > string length.

Comment: @Gordon, Svish: My N will never exceed string length.

Comment: @gameover: ok, then I suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. For $n > strlen($str) you can do $n %= strlen($str) and then the solution provided by stereofrog.

Comment: @Ch4m3l3on See my alternative below for the modulo version

Comment: @Gordon Yeah, I haven't noticed that, sorry. Anyway, that's the proper way to do it :).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one variant that allows arbitrary shifting to the left and right, regardless of the length of the input string:

```
function str_shift($str, $len) {
    $len = $len % strlen($str);
    return substr($str, $len) . substr($str, 0, $len);
}

echo str_shift('abcdef', -2);  // efabcd
echo str_shift('abcdef', 2);   // cdefab
echo str_shift('abcdef', 11);  // fabcde
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function rotate_string ($str, $n)
{
    while ($n > 0)
    {
        $str = substr($str, 1) . substr($str, 0, 1);
        $n--;
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function for this but is easily implemented.

```
function rotate_left($s) {
  return substr($s, 1) . $s[0];
}

function rotate_right($s) {
  return substr($s, -1) . substr($s, 0, -1);
}
```

You could extend this to add an optional parameter for the number of characters to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rotate_string($str) {
    for ($i=1; $i<strlen($str)+1;$i++) {
        @$string .= substr($str , strlen($str)-$i , 1);
    }
    return $string;
}

echo rotate_string("string"); //gnirts
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code

```
<?php
    $str = "helloworld" ;
    $res = string_function($str,3) ;
    print_r ( $res) ;
    function string_function ( $str , $count )
    {
    $arr = str_split ( $str );
    for ( $i=0; $i<$count ; $i++ )
    {
      $element = array_pop ( $arr ) ;
      array_unshift ( $arr, $element ) ;
    }
    $result=( implode ( "",$arr )) ;
    return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get N rotated strings like this.

```
$str = "Vijaysinh";
$arr1 = str_split($str);
$rotated = array();
$i=0;


    foreach($arr1 as $a){
        $t = $arr1[$i];
        unset($arr1[$i]);
        $rotated[] = $t.implode($arr1);
        $arr1[$i] = $t;
        $i++; 
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($rotated);exit;
```